# AutoHotkey: Why do hotkeys break remappings?

Tags: autohotkey

I want to swap <kbd>LAlt</kbd> with <kbd>LCtrl</kbd>, which is straightforward enough by itself:

```
#SingleInstance Force
#UseHook
#MenuMaskKey VKFF
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
SendMode Input
LAlt::RCtrl
RCtrl::LAlt
```

It just works. But the main reason I want to do it is to block <kbd>LAlt</kbd>'s function as a menu key. I want combinations of the physical <kbd>LAlt</kbd> button with <kbd>J</kbd>, <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd>, <kbd>I</kbd> to function as Arrow keys and <kbd>LAlt</kbd> not being completely silenced means I cannot use those to navigate context menus — since <kbd>Alt</kbd> closes them on key-down. And it is exactly what happens if I add `<!i::Send {Up}` to the script. Now <kbd>LAlt</kbd> isn't blocked on key-down — pressing it now shows underscores up top under menu option names, which wasn't the case previously, and any open context menu will be closed.

So my main question is: **Why does this happen? Why do (additional) hotkeys break remappings and what ways are there of preventing\working around\dealing with that?**

Now, one way I know how to fix this is to use `>^i::Send {Up}` and, since the hotkey doesn't work otherwise, remove `SendMode Input`. But the docs say `SendInput` is better and thus I chose another way — split the script in two and have one run the other.

```
; Script One:                                   ; Script Two (two.ahk):

#SingleInstance Force                            #SingleInstance Force
#UseHook                                         #UseHook
#MenuMaskKey VKFF                                #MenuMaskKey VKFF
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%                      SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
SendMode Input                                   SendMode Input

Run two.ahk                                      >^i::Send {RCtrl up}{Up}{RCtrl down}
                                                 >^k::Send {RCtrl up}{Down}{RCtrl down}
LAlt::RCtrl                                      >^j::Send {RCtrl up}{Left}{RCtrl down}
RCtrl::LAlt                                      >^l::Send {RCtrl up}{Right}{RCtrl down}
Capslock::Backspace                              >^o::Send +{F10}
```

This seems to work fine, but is there a better way I can achieve what I want? Like doing it in one file, keeping `SendMode Input` and not having to neutralize <kbd>RCtrl</kbd> with `{RCtrl up} ... {RCtrl down}`?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> Although a remapped key can trigger normal hotkeys, by default it cannot trigger mouse hotkeys or hook hotkeys

Since you have `#UseHook`, I think if you play with `#InputLevel` you can do what you want https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_InputLevel.htm

Comment: I don't see how this quote explains why adding `<!i::Send {Up}` makes `LAlt::RCtrl` stop working. And `#InputLevel` doesn't work with `SendInput`.

Comment: Did you read the part about '#UseHook'? See the 'Remark' section https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm. '...by default it cannot trigger mouse hotkeys or hook hotkeys ...'  The docs also say that if two scripts are using '#UseHook' it disables one of them: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendInputDetail so it reverts to 'Event'.